# Hosting options for running a daily run python script which creates a CSV file?

Tags: web-hosting, amazon-aws, cloud-hosting, python, azure

I wish to run a Python script that daily pulls in some prices and creates a CSV file from them.

What web hosting and cloud options exist to do this.

The script will only run for literally seconds and the CSV file is very small so not much resources at all. I suppose the problem being the Python setup/installation.

https://www.pythonanywhere.com seems an option, but want to pay the least amount for this.

Is it possible to do this with AWS, Azure or another Cloud service and which services would I need?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you toy get an VPS with SSH support, which gives you a total control to do everything you want with the server.

Then u could just make a cron task to execute your script daily

Comment: Bit more hard work setting up Pyhton though I assume, plus AWS has a free tier that should cover this?